# Is there a good xypic editor?

Tags: xy-pic

I'm using LyX for my LaTeX editing, and I use LyX's matrix editing capabilities to edit `xypic` matrices. While this is much more comfortable than editing raw `xypic` LaTeX code, it can get quite messy when I try to use it for large graphs.

Is there any graphical `xypic` editor that can help me with that? A program that allows me to graphically draw graphs, and export them as `xypic` LaTeX code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the single word "No".

Answer (score 2):

Inside Lyx you can easily compose XY-Pic figures.
With instant preview activated, you can see the result immediately without recompiling.
The following picture should give you an idea what this amounts to::

[image]

If this is what you are interested in, check [the manual at my homepage](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~gumm/LyX/Using_XYpic_in_LyX.htm).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really help me. My problem is not previewing the xypic diagram - my problem is editing complex diagrams, that get to wide to fit in the screen(and then I have to zoom out, and it get's difficult to read the text etc...). With the instant preview I still need to edit the xypic diagrams using the matrix interface, so it doesn't solve the problem.